# Difference between array<<element and array.push(element)? or string<<"something" and string+"something"? in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Before judging me for an irrelevant question, I'll safeguard myself, that I know << is a bitwise operator. However, in both cases (array, string) it operates as just adding / concatenating values.

Any tip for clarifying whether there's difference if we use array<

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in both cases (array, string) it operates as just adding /
>   concatenating values.

It makes no difference "result-wise" - in both cases you get a value containing both operands (in that or another form).

The difference shows up in the way operands are impacted:

- one performs in-place mutating
- second is simply concatenating without changing the original strings.

Consider the following examples:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
```

Now:

```
# concatenation - no changes to original strings
a + b #=> "ab"
a     #=> "a"
b     #=> "b"
```

Whereas:

```
# mutation - original string is changed in-place
a << b #=> "ab"
a      #=> "ab"
```

Same goes with arrays:

```
# concatenation - no changes to original arrays
a = ['a'] #=> ["a"]
b = ['b'] #=> ["b"]
a + b     #=> ["a", "b"]
a         #=> ["a"]
b         #=> ["b"]

# mutation - original array is changed in-place
a << b #=> ["a", ["b"]]
a      #=> ["a", ["b"]]
```

As to [Array#`push`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push) and  [Array#`<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) - they do the same thing.

Comment: a="a"
b="b"

c=a+b vs c=a<<b ?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri in first example you get the `c` but your `a` and `b` are not changed. In second, you get `c`, but your `a` is mutated.. Why not just check it in console? :)

Comment: Did I ask what happens to a and b ? :) no.. believe it or not, I can use irb as well.. :) I'm asking question about operation result.. if I'll store the result in variable c, then it doesn't matter result-wise.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri well, if you can take a look into my answer, it clearly **does answer** the question and states the difference between concatenation and mutation. If you would have asked if there where any difference while assigning **the result** to a variable - i would have answered this, too. So let me emphasize it here: it **does not** matter "result-wise" as long as you **do not** care about `a` and `b`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `<<` is not a bit-wise operator. Nor is `:<<` or `"<<"`. The first is not a Ruby object or keyword. `:<<` is a symbol and `"<<"` is a string. [Fixnum#<<](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-3C-3C), by constrast, is a bit-wise operator, implemented as an instance method on the class `Fixnum`.

You may argue that it's obvious what you meant, but it's not. Many classes have instance methods of the same name that are unrelated. Several classes, for example, have methods called `"<<"`, `"+"`, `"size"`, `"replace"`, `"select"`, `"each"` and on and on. The only way to speak meaningfully of an instance method, therefore, is to also give the class on which it is defined.

What is an "operator" in Ruby? Frankly, I don't know. I've never found a definition. Whatever it is, however, most of them are implemented as instance methods.

Many of Ruby's core methods have names that may seem unusual to those coming from other languages.  Examples are `"<<"`, `"+"` and `"&"`. The important thing to remember is that these are perfectly-valid names. Let's try using them as you would any other method:

```
[1,2,3].<<(4)    #=> [1, 2, 3, 4] 
"cat".+("hat")   #=> "cathat" 
[1,2,3].&([2,4]) #=> [2]
```

The head Ruby monk knew that his disciples would prefer to write these as follows:

```
[1,2,3] << 4
"cat" + "hat"
[1,2,3] & [2,4]
```

so he said "OK", which when translated from Japanese to English means "OK". He simply designed the Ruby parser so that when it saw the later form it would convert the expression to the standard form before parsing it further (or something like that). This has come to be called *syntactic sugar*. (Syntactic sugar doesn't allow you to write `"cat" concat "hat"`, however--it only applies to names that are made up of symbols.)

My point with Ruby's operators is that most are implement with garden-variety methods, albeit methods with odd-sounding names. Yes, there are methods [String#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2B) and [Array#+](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) but they are completely unrelated to each other. If they were instead named `String#str_add` and `Array#arr_add` and used like so:

```
"abc".str_add("def")
[1,2,3].arr_add([2,4])
```

you probably wouldn't be asking the question you've raised.